# Array format to JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

Using this array value change this to JSON format.

```
    $prices = array("250", "350", "400", "678", "800", "1000");
    var opt = {
    milestones: {
    1: {
         mlPos: 250, ---> (set $price value)
         mlId: false,
         mlClass: 'bi-custom',
         mlDim: '200%',
         mlLabel: 'Milestone one',
         mlLabelVis: 'hover',
         mlHoverRange: 15,
         mlLineWidth: 1
       },
    2: {
        mlPos: 350, ---> (set $price value)
        mlId: false,
        mlClass: 'bi-custom',
        mlDim: '200%',
        mlLabel: 'Milestone two',
        mlLabelVis: 'hover',
        mlHoverRange: 15,
        mlLineWidth: 1
     },
     3: {
       mlPos: 400, ---> (set $price value)
       mlId: false,
       mlClass: 'bi-custom',
       mlDim: '200%',
       mlLabel: 'Milestone one',
       mlLabelVis: 'hover',
       mlHoverRange: 15,
       mlLineWidth: 1
     },
  4: {
      mlPos: 678,---> (set $price value)
      mlId: false,
      mlClass: 'bi-custom',
      mlDim: '200%',
      mlLabel: 'Milestone two',
      mlLabelVis: 'hover',
      mlHoverRange: 15,
      mlLineWidth: 1
    },
 5: {
     mlPos: 800,---> (set $price value)
     mlId: false,
     mlClass: 'bi-custom',
     mlDim: '200%',
     mlLabel: 'Milestone two',
     mlLabelVis: 'hover',
     mlHoverRange: 15,
     mlLineWidth: 1
   }
 }
};
```

We have the php variable in array format `$price` convert in javascript variable like this json format,problem is not for converting php variable into javascript variable problem is just convert the php array into  json format like above format.

anyone please help

Thank You.

Comment: Look up [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes i tried, manually insert some value like mIId:false,MIClass:bi-custom etc.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to run PHP code on the browser! PHP only runs on the server! Javascript runs in the browser! If I am wrong here you will need to make your question **much more clear**

Comment: @RiggsFolly already mention variable conversion is not the problem, Just convert php array into  this json format, now clear

Comment: No. The code you have shown has no context. Is this in a PHP script? Is this in a javascript fragment within a PHP script? Is this javascript as seen from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) cast the arrays into objects, you can also use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option for that:

```
$prices = array( "250", "350", "400", "678", "800", "1000" );

$row = [
    'mlPos'         => null,
    'mlId'          => false,
    'mlClass'       => 'bi-custom',
    'mlDim'         => '200%',
    'mlLabel'       => 'Milestone two',
    'mlLabelVis'    => 'hover',
    'mlHoverRange'  => 15,
    'mlLineWidth'   => 1
];

$rows = [];
foreach( $prices as $price ) {
    $rows[] = (object) array_replace( $row, [ 'mlPos' => $price ] );
}

$opt = [ 'milestones' => (object) $rows ];


echo json_encode( $opt,  JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );

// output {"milestones":{"0":{"mlPos":"250","mlId":false,"mlClass":"bi-custom", ...
```

Comment: @Danijiel Thanks the code is working fine, small doubt i need :)

Answer (score 0):

Please mention what expected format you need in json and from what input you need to convert to json.

```
JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
```

The above will do what you require. but for providing answer please explain clearly.

I think you use CakePHP 3.0 also?

http://php.net/json_encode

You can get answers from there or use this link before implementing,

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php

Please be precise in your question.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

json_encode is available in php > 5.2.0:

```
echojson_encode($row);
```

Comment: I have sent array value i need the code to code to convert that array value into this json format

Comment: @Karthik: Above line converts your php array to json Object.

Comment: Do you need internal conversion code????

Comment: Yes, I need code to add the  mlId: false, etc value into array